# WAR is getting corrupted , if I try to create an WAR of 1GB files using Maven

Tags: maven, war

War is corrupted and getting an error of **Unable to load MetDemo.war: Invalid file - not a PKZip file**
when tried to expand it.
If I try to make an WAR by removing some contents then its working fine and deployed in server.
but if i tried to create an WAR with 1 GB content and WAR is getting corrupted .

Also tried updating the WAR plugin to the recent version but no luck
Is there is any size limit for generating the WAR.

Comment: Could you add some information why your war file is so extremely large? Typical war files are < 50MB.

Comment: code doesn't increase war file size, the dependencies that you add in build path does. show us your pom file

Comment: I would advise you to split up the war into several wars for different purposes. Furthermore, I would review if you really need all the dependencies you package into your war. Nobody designed Maven or application servers for wars > 100MB, so you are more or less on your own when you work with 1GB wars.

Comment: ya I agree, my question here is , if 800 MB code base is generated as 400 MB war and working correctly .why not 1 GB code base is not generating correctly and generating corrupted WAR. increased in code base size is because of the Html files that i have added.

Comment: Actually My application code base is large , since it supports large number of portals. and i can assure that it doesn't have any unneeded code. the problem here is , if i have tried to generate a war by removing some of the code of around 200 MB , then it is generating war of 400 MB which is working fine in server too. but if i tried to make a war with 1 GB , in this case it is generating war of 499 MB corrupted WAR. Is this because of maven restrictions in large code base ?

Comment: I would really check if WAR files have a limitation ? The question is what kind of error the server is showing ...Which server do you use? Apart from that ..having a WAR file for 1 GiB I would suggest to reconsider the the usage of such thing it takes very long time to unpack etc. and I have my doubts that it belongs into a single WAR file...(as already mentioned). What I don't understand is: You can have 200MB code (source code size?) and generating a 400 MiB WAR ? .. Do you have many resources in your WAR file?

Comment: the whole code belong to a single WAR file , Actually i am using 1GB code base to generate an WAR , which in turns generates an  490 MB WAR file .
the problem here , when this 490 MB war is added as an dependency to generate an EAR . which is not getting deployed in the WAS server .
and deployment hungs at the install ear step .

Comment: You are using your WAS outside the range it was tested and designed for. Building and deploying such large WARs may or may not work depending on the circumstances. The recommended solution would be to split your code base and build five or ten separate WARs.

Comment: splitting the single war in to three wars and adding it as an dependency to the EAR. will try this one